# IHttpClientFactory for full framework (4.7) and IoC

Tags: inversion-of-control, dotnet-httpclient, .net-4.7.2, httpclientfactory, ihttpclientfactory

I am trying to Register IHttpClientFactory in Full Framework 4.7 (not core).
I am using IoC container (LightInject)

Problem, that I do not have direct access to implementation of internal class DefaultHttpClientFactory
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs
This class is not visible because it is not public.
I found solution as 3rd party implementation - https://github.com/uhaciogullari/HttpClientFactoryLite
, bit it uses its own interface.

Is it possible to use interface IHttpClientFactory with IoC for Full Framework(not .net core)?

In case it is possible , what class can i use as implementation for IHttpClientFactory during registration for IoC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was suggested in [this github issue](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/843) you can use this:

```cs
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection().AddHttpClient().BuildServiceProvider();
container.RegisterInstance(serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>());
container.ContainerScope.RegisterForDisposal(serviceProvider);
```

- `AddHttpClient` [registers](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L37) the `DefaultHttpClientFactory` for `IHttpClientFactory`
- Then you can retrieve it from the DI container

This sample uses `SimpleInjector` but the same concept can be applied for any other DI framework.